# How to make a loop for variadic params?

Tags: swift, loops, variadic

```
func y1(_ data: [Double], _ par: Double...) -> Double {
//some maths
}

func test(_ y:(_ data: [Double], _ par: Double...) -> Double, _ data: [Double], _ x: [Double]...) -> [Double] {
var opt_par = [Double]()
// ?
return opt_par
}

let par_1 = Array(stride(from: 0, through: 1, by: 0.5))
let par_2 = Array(stride(from: 0, through: 2, by: 0.5))
test(y1, data_arr, par_1, par_2)
```

Hi! We have 2 parameters: par_1 and par_2 to pass to y1. y1 is called through func test. How to make a loop in func test to call y1 with different sets of variables? In this case: 0 0 ; 0 0.5 ; ... ; 1 2 - totally 3*5 = 15 sets

ps: there could be up to 10 or more variadic parameters

Comment: the same say you do for any collection `for double in par {
        print(double)
    }`

Comment: double == [0.0, 0.5, 1.0] and [0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0]. but how do i call y1?

Comment: I think I understand your confusion. You don't want to simply iterate, you want to pass an array value to a variadic parameter, right? Why are you using variadic params in the first place?

Comment: I want test func to call y1(data, 0,0); y1(data,0,0.5); y1(data, 0, 1.0); y1(data, 0.5, 0) .... and so on.

Comment: Swift doesn't support array splatting, so you can't use an array to feed the arguments of a variadic parameter.

Comment: what is the easiest solution in this case?